# How to convert binary file into readable format on linux server

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am trying to convert binary file into readable format but unable to do so, please suggest how it could be achieved.

```
$ file test.docx
test.docx: Microsoft Word 2007+
$ file -i test.docx
test.docx: application/msword; charset=binary
$

>>> raw = codecs.open('test.docx', encoding='ascii').readlines()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/Python/installPath/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 694, in readlines
    return self.reader.readlines(sizehint)
  File "/home/Python/installPath/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 603, in readlines
    data = self.read()
  File "/home/Python/installPath/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 492, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "readable"? What is it that you want to "read"?

Comment: File is MS Word format which i can read on windows machine, now when i upload it on server, i cannot read the text in order to perform some search operations in file.

Comment: There are several free products for Linux that will read MS Word files, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18223/how-to-read-word-doc-files

Comment: I already tried antiword and catdoc, that didn't help. When i execute `antiword` then error is `test.docx is not a Word Document.` and when i run catdoc then error is `This file looks like ZIP archive or Office 2007 or later file.
Not supported by catdoc`

Comment: And you can open the file from Word itself? Which Word version do you have, and which version of antiword?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to read it in binary mode :

```
import binascii
with open('test.docx', 'rb') as f: # 'rb' stands for read binary
    hexdata = binascii.hexlify(f.read()) # convert to hex
    print(hexdata)
```

Comment: I tried this but still cant read the content. output is something like **▒V7߿>▒▒̬;▒▒ɫ**   this is just part of the output, thats how complete files reads up .

Comment: you can't just read binary data this way.
you could convert it to hexadecimal or something.
I've updated my answer.

Comment: So you mean i cannot read this binary file into text format ? Actually this is a MS word file which i uploaded to server and on server i cannot read it. Is there no way to read it in original text readable format ?

Comment: No. A binary is not readable as plain text
Maybe you could try on linux : `strings test.docx`

Comment: Don't you have something like OpenOffice?  The problem with MS office files is that it can retain "old" text with editing history.  `strings` or `od -c` will get the text, but whether it make sense or not is another matter.

Comment: On linux you could use :
`libreoffice --headless --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" test.docx`

You need libre office installed

Comment: @Loïc I tried what you suggested. `/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display:
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
` is the error. I am running this with root user so should not be permission issue.

Comment: Using --headless it shouldn't be looking for X. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, [Working with Binary Data](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-binary-data-python)

```
with open("test_file.docx", "rb") as binary_file:
# Read the whole file at once
data = binary_file.read()
print(data)

# Seek position and read N bytes
binary_file.seek(0)  # Go to beginning
couple_bytes = binary_file.read(2)
print(couple_bytes)
```

Comment: I tried this but still cant read the content. output is something like **▒V7߿>▒▒̬;▒▒ɫ**  . THis is just part of the output for first half and for second half output is **PK**

Answer (score 0):

I think others have not answered this question - at least the part as @ankitpandey clarified in his comment about catdoc returning an error

> " catdoc then error is This file looks like ZIP archive or Office 2007
> or later file. Not supported by catdoc"

I too had just encountered this same issue with catdoc, had found this solution that worked for me

the .zip archive mention was a clue - and I was able to the following command

```
unzip  -q -c 'test.docx' word/document.xml  | python etree.py
```

to extract the text portion of test.docx to stdout

the python code was placed in etree.py

```
from lxml import etree
import sys

xml = sys.stdin.read().encode('utf-8')
root = etree.fromstring(xml)

bits_of_text = root.xpath('//text()')
# print(bits_of_text)  # Note that some bits are whitespace-only
joined_text = ' '.join(
    bit.strip() for bit in bits_of_text
    if bit.strip() != ''
)
print(joined_text)
```